# How to convert some String fields of a list of entities to date while iterating in Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-time

I am having a list of entities which having various values including some string fields which i want to convert to as date.

```
N_year_month=20010125, N_sequence_num=1, M_sequence_num=0, N_creation_date=20010109, N_check_date=20010211, _status=H, _frequency=A, _record=0
```

My requirement is to convert the N_year_month,N_creation_date,N_check_date into date while returning the list.

I am posting the code i have written

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter_1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

public List<NEntity> fetch(List<SearchCriteria> params){
    CriteriaQuery<NEntity> query = getNListDetailEntityCriteriaQuery(params);
    List<NEntity> nEntityDetailsList = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();//in this line i am getting the data from the database 
    pmmEntityDetailsList.stream()
    .map(i->LocalDate.parse(i.N_year_month(),formatter_1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());// Here i have tried to convert the String into date
     int count = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().size();
     entityManager.close();
     return nEntityDetailsList;
}
```

I have tried to convert one field into date using stream api of Java 8 , but i am having exception.My exception is below

```
{
"errorMessage": "Something went wrong!",
"errorDetails": "Text '20010125' could not be parsed at index 0",
"timestamp": "2021-01-06 10:29:48",
"status": 500
}
```

How i can convert these 3 fields N_year_month,N_creation_date,N_check_date  into Date(yyyy-mm-dd format) while returning the list nEntityDetailsList;

Comment: Your date pattern has "-", the field data doesn't.

Comment: Your stream operation creates a new list, but then you're returning the original list. Why not `return pmmEntityDetailsList.stream().map(...).collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Comment: @MikeFHay how i will apply to these 3items

Comment: You may use [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE) to parse a string like `20010125`.